# ubuntu: installing apache ant apache-ant-1.10.1

Tags: ant, ubuntu-14.04

```
$ ant -version
/home/rahul/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/bin/java: 6: /home/rahul/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/bin/java: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to install Apache Ant in Ubuntu-

**Using Ubuntu Package Manager**

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install ant
```

**Manual Steps**

```
wget http://www-eu.apache.org/dist//ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.10.5-bin.zip    
unzip apache-ant-1.10.5-bin.zip -d /usr/local/    
cd /usr/local/    
mv apache-ant-1.10.5 apache-ant    
ln -s /usr/local/apache-ant/ /usr/local/ant

vim /etc/profile.d/ant.sh
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/ant
export PATH=${ANT_HOME}/bin:${PATH}


source /etc/profile    
ant –version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.5 compiled on July 10 2018
```

Comment: Now is published the version 1.10.6, do you know how much time it takes to get it into Ubuntu repositories? Or will it be added at all in the current ubuntu release?